# error with (sudo apt-get update ) in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, updates, ppa, 20.04

that is the error wich appear when i try to update

E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/fingerprint/fprint/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

Answer (score 0):

This error message tells you, that the given repository does not support the Focal Fossa release.

The fprint library is included in the official repository as `libfprint`. I would recommend removing the launchpad repo by going into the "Software & Updates" and unticking it under "Other software".
The error should go away and you may install the library from the official repo (it may already by installed).